# Gradle DSL method not found:comple()

Tags: android, gradle, youtube-api

I am new to android coding and was trying to add the youtube API to my APP. But i keep hitting on this error.I have tried the solutions from other links but I am not able to resolve the issue.Can someone help me out?

My app->build.gradle looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.vidhya.youtubeplayer"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
comple files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

My gradle->build.gradle looks this way

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}    }

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Kindly help.

Comment: please, before asking at least search for the typos

Comment: @Selvin if you are talking about comple(), then I am right in typing coz that is exactly what is coming in my android error screen.Have attached image for reference http://imgur.com/2ZC4wWM

Comment: who upvote this question? +1 for typo? , yeah, I'm sure that it will help everyone in the future ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    comple files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

Comment: Thank you and Sorry for wasting your time!